# Installing 10.10+ with Radeon HD 6970 Video Card

Tags: boot, radeon

I built a new PC that has a Diamond Radeon HD 6970 graphics card, and no on-board graphics. When I boot from the Ubuntu disc, it runs through some initial booting stuff, and then gets to a loading screen that just has the Ubuntu logo and some progress bar/dot thingies. After this screen is finished, it goes black and says it cannot display video mode.

I've seen many people that say to simply install the ati drivers. However, I don't believe this is an option, because I can't even get to the boot screen that asks me if I want to run the system off of the LiveCD, boot to hard disk, etc...

Is there a way to somehow boot to a CLI before getting to the screen that would normally let me choose that? I'm at a loss as far as what to do.

Also:

1. Yes, the CD boots fine on other machines. (I've also burnt a couple discs just to be sure)
2. Yes, the graphics card is fine. I normally dual-boot with Windows 7, and it runs on Windows just fine.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have nomodeset selected before booting into the live cd. After you install ubuntu hold shift during the boot process to get to the grub menu, now edit the boot options and add nomodeset to the list of items, you can remove nosplash if you want to see what happening during bootup. Once you get into Ubuntu go to system/Admin./Hardware drivers. If its already installed, at the grub menu select recovery mode and you will be able to drop to a root shell prompt.